# ACF set gallery thumbnail custom sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

THis is php code of ACF Gallery

```
              <?php 

                $gallery = get_field('slider_1_gallery');

                if( $gallery ): 

                    ?>
                    <div class="big_slider">
                        <?php foreach( $gallery as $index=>$image ): ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="miniature_slider">
                        <?php foreach( $gallery as $index=>$image ): ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="miniature" data-fancybox = "1">
                                    <img src="<?php echo  $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                    <div class="mask">
                                        <i class="icon_1"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Thumbnails has default sizes. But I need custom sizes for this images

```
<img src="<?php echo  $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

How is possible to set 
width = 165 pixels
height = 110 pixels 
in ACF Gallery ?
Is possible do this with scale and crop?

Comment: If you need to add width and height for each image then you need to add it as inline style in img tag itself directly like eg: <img style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="<?php echo  $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give custom size then add this code to function.php:

```
<?php
    add_image_size( 'people-img', 360, 360, true ); 
?>
```

After that you need to fetch like this :

```
<?php
        $attachment_id = get_field('bio_image');
        $size = "people-img"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
        // url = $image[0];
        // width = $image[1];
        // height = $image[2];
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" >
```

Comment: I can't do how. $attachment_id = get_field('bio_image');  I have array $image. Is ACF Gallery, this isn't standart wordpress script.

Comment: @Denis this one is ACF's script. you will get image array using this and then you can use image url.